# For what purposes default BeagleBone Black debian image runs /usr/bin/nodejs?

Tags: beagleboneblack

For what purposes default BeagleBone Black debian image runs /usr/bin/nodejs ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are running a [Beagleboard.org debian image](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images).

Those images are specifically crafted for Beagleboard SBCs and include packages that allow even a beginner to get easily started. Some of them even include a graphical desktop environment, accessible on boards with HDMI.

NodeJS is going to be needed at least for the Cloud9 IDE that those images ship with.

Those images are not optimized nor intended to be a baseline for ambitious embedded projects. Should you desire a much more barebones (no pun intended) image, then you should check out the more limited images, especially "console" images, or purpose build your own images, be it with the beagle Debian scripts or with one of many embedded Linux build systems (Buildroot, something from the Yocto project, etc.)